# How to perform a DNS lookup on multiple array elements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, node-modules, es6-promise

I'm working on project that generate domain name, but before sending the result I want to verify the domain name generated is available using the built it nodejs dns library. The problem I'm facing is that the program returns before the callback is executed.

This is what I tried. The function returns an empty array when it ought to return an array of available domain names

```
const domainVerify = (generatedNames)=>{
  var validDomains = []
  for (var i in generatedNames){
      dns.lookup(i, (err, value)=>{
          if(!err) validDomains.push(i)
      })
  }
  return validDomains
}


const generatedNames = ["google.com", "abdefg.com"]
console.log(domainVerify(generatedNames))
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to promisify the `lookup` function to resolve to a boolean:

```
const lookupPromise = name => new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    dns.lookup(name, err => resolve(!err))
);
```

Then you can use `Promise.all` to get a promise that resolves when all lookups have responses:

```
const domainVerify = generatedNames =>
    Promise.all(generatedNames.map(lookupPromise)).then(arr =>
        arr.map((bool, i) => bool && generatedNames[i]).filter(Boolean)
    );
```

Now `domainVerify` is that promise you need to await to resolve. So you could chain a `then` call to it:

```
const generatedNames = ["google.com", "abdefg.com"]
domainVerify(generatedNames).then(name => {
    console.log(name); 
    // ...etc
});
```